# this.props.token is null in the componentDidMount but not in other functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to fetch some results from my backend. Its a filtered array. I used to filter the array in my backend but i decided to try and filter the results in my frontend. I had this code that worked fine:

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Suggestions from './Suggestions/Suggestions';

import styles from './Search.module.css';

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  }

  fetchSearchResults = () => {
    console.log(this.state.query);
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/search?username=' + this.state.query.toString() + '&limit=7', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch status');
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(resData => {
        this.setState({
          results: resData.users.map(user => {
            return{...user};
          })
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      query: this.search.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.fetchSearchResults();
        }
      } else if (!this.state.query) {
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.isAuth && (
          <Fragment>
            <form className={styles.search}>
              <input
                id={styles.myInput}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search..."
                ref={input => this.search = input}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              />
            </form>
            <Suggestions results={this.state.results} />
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Search
```

this search component is part of the mainNavigation i have implemented, which is being called from my App.js file. And its working. I can see results after the search.

Now i tried to add this:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  fetchUsers = () => {
    console.log(this.props.token);
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch users.');
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      this.setState({ 
        users: resData.users.map(user => {
          return {
            ...user
          };
        })
      });
    })
    .catch(this.catchError);
  };
```

so i fetch all the users and i would filter the list later. But `this.props.token` is null and i am getting an error from my backend

```
name: 'JsonWebTokenError',
message: 'jwt malformed',
statusCode: 500
```

I also tried it with `componentWillRecieveProps()` but `this.props.token` is still null.
I have no idea why this is happening. I never had a similar error in my other components when i was trying to fetch something in the `componentDidMount()`

Edit:

parent component (MainNavigatoin.js)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import MobileToggle from '../MobileToggle/MobileToggle';
import Logo from '../../Logo/Logo';
import NavigationItems from '../NavigationItems/NavigationItems';
import Search from '../../Search/Search';

import styles from './MainNavigation.module.css';

const mainNavigation = props => (
  <nav className={styles.mainNav}>
    <MobileToggle onOpen={props.onOpenMobileNav} />
    <div className={styles.mainNav__logo} >
      <NavLink to="/">
        <Logo />
      </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.spacer} />
    <div className={styles.mainNav__logo} >
        <Search isAuth={props.isAuth} token={props.token} history={props.history} />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.spacer} />
    <ul className={styles.mainNav__items}>
      <NavigationItems userId={props.userId} isAuth={props.isAuth} onLogout={props.onLogout} />
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

export default mainNavigation;
```

parent component of MainNavigation is App.js (a lot of unnecessary things in my App.js. Here is the return of the render method of my App.j)s:

```js
return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.state.showBackdrop && (
          <Backdrop onClick={this.backdropClickHandler} />
        )}
        <ErrorHandler error={this.state.error} onHandle={this.errorHandler} />
        <Layout
          header={
            <Toolbar>
              <MainNavigation
                onOpenMobileNav={this.mobileNavHandler.bind(this, true)}
                onLogout={this.logoutHandler}
                isAuth={this.state.isAuth}
                userId={this.state.userId}
                token={this.state.token}
                history={this.props.history}
              />
            </Toolbar>
          }
          mobileNav={
            <MobileNavigation
              open={this.state.showMobileNav}
              mobile
              onChooseItem={this.mobileNavHandler.bind(this, false)}
              onLogout={this.logoutHandler}
              isAuth={this.state.isAuth}
              userId={this.state.userId}
            />
          }
        />
        {routes}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit 2:
my login handler where my token is being set:

```js
loginHandler = (event, authData) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ authLoading: true });
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: authData.email,
        password: authData.password
      })
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 422) {
          throw new Error('Validation failed.');
        }
        if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
          console.log('Error!');
          throw new Error('Could not authenticate you!');
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(resData => {
        // console.log(resData);
        this.setState({
          isAuth: true,
          token: resData.token,
          authLoading: false,
          userId: resData.userId
        });
        localStorage.setItem('token', resData.token);
        localStorage.setItem('userId', resData.userId);
        const remainingMilliseconds = 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const expiryDate = new Date(
          new Date().getTime() + remainingMilliseconds
        );
        localStorage.setItem('expiryDate', expiryDate.toISOString());
        this.setAutoLogout(remainingMilliseconds);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({
          isAuth: false,
          authLoading: false,
          error: err
        });
      });
  };
```

Note: token is not null in my project. this.state.token is null in this component in this function called `fetchUsers`. In `fetchSearchResults` it is not null and i am fetching results from my backend. I have too many other components that are working fine in this project. And this Search component is working fine and token is not null when i am not using the `componentDidMount()` and the `fetchUsers` i specify in my second code block in this post. When `fetchSearchResults` (from my first code block) is being executed the token has a value and it is working fine.

Comment: what are we looking at? is the second block of code in a different component? is that the same block of code as the top one?

Comment: @Oliver as I said I added the second block to my component from the first block. I didn't paste the whole component in the second block cause i just added it in the same component i provided in the first block. obviously i also added the ```users``` element in my state

Comment: @Morgana no i don't use redux. I am just receiving the token as props when i call the search component from my MainNavigation.js file

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the fetchUsers method within the Search class constructor to allow the function to access the props/states.

add this to your Search class:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this);
  }
```

See this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for more details

EDIT:
Just to test my theory that this is due to the token not being set yet in the app.js before the method in search is getting called, try this:

```
    fetchUsers = () => {
    console.log(this.props.token);
    if(this.props.token){
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch users.');
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      this.setState({ 
        users: resData.users.map(user => {
          return {
            ...user
          };
        })
      });
    })
    .catch(this.catchError);
}
  };
```

When the token will be set in app.js the render methods of child componens will be called, so change the render method of search.js to call the fetchusers function

Comment: `this.props.token` is still null after adding the constructor in the Search class. It is still throwing the same error

Comment: @gevor how is the token being populated? can you show the parent component's code?

Comment: I added some parent components up to the App.js. I have to say again that i never had any similar error, even though i am fetching data quite a lot of times in  `ComponentDidMount()` calls in many components i am using in my project

Comment: @gover in app.js console.log the token to check it is not null there because the code doesnt show how it is getting populated still (or you can post the bit where the token is being populated..)

Comment: i added some more code if you want to check it but generally token has a value and everything in my project is working perfectly. even this component, the Search component, is working fine if i exclude the `componentDidMount()` and the `fetchUsers`.

Comment: Ah... took me way too long to figure out, the issue is that the token is retrieved in a async method, so the component search is mounted and this new function is called before token is set, see updated answer in a minute @gevor

Comment: its is not throwing an error anymore. but i never actually fetch the users. cause when `fetchUsers` is being called the `this.props.token` is still not set so it is not executing the fetch method.

Comment: did you add the fetchUser to the render method like i said at the end of the edit?

Comment: But to get it straight i want to ask you something. I am fetching data inside the `componentDidMount()` a lot in my project. And i never had this error before. So the problem is that this MainNavigation component is being called in my App.js before i actually call the routes so loginHandler has not yet been executed so I dont have a token set? does this make sense? How can i use the token in the exact same way in other components but in this one? @Unknown

Comment: when i actually call the fetchUsers in the render method i am sending infinite requests to my backend

Comment: the proper way is to display a loading screen until your desired states have been populated. So in the render method of app.js add the condition that checks if the state 'token' is populated, if it is not then return the loading screen component (could  literally just be a spinner or some text saying please wait), if the state is populated THEN return the components, let me know if this doesnt make sense

Comment: when i actually call the fetchUsers in the render method i am sending infinite requests to my backend - yes that was just for testing to see if that was the issue, to fix it use the solution above or in the fetchUsers method add the condition to check is user is null, then send the request only if users state is null